# wordpress : add_action : why the second parameter is an array instead of a function name

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a wordpress plugin, I found one plugin which use oops concepts, my question is why the second parameter in the add_action function is an array instead of a function name

> add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,
>   'my_menu'));

my_menu is a function in the same class, please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Because the second argument needs to be a [callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback). (and `add_action` internally uses [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)).

For functions we can just pass its name as a string but we can't do that with object methods, can we?

So an array is passed with 2 elements, first the object and second the method to call:-

`array( $object, 'method' )`

Oh and you can safely remove that useless '&', PHP4 days are gone now.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the advice here. I'm nearly understanding but can you help with this example. I'm not sure how to reference $object when we are working with value => key:          add_action( 'woo_main_before', 'woo_slider_biz', 10, array( 
                        'slide_page' => 394,
                        'use_slide_page' => true
                        
                        ) );

Comment: I'm having a constant issue where $object behaves as if I used $this and I get an error stating that the class add_action() was used in does not have the method hooked. I'm even creating a new object and passing it on the line before add_action but it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

@Thomas John, you are correct about second argument in add_action also in wordpress org not mentioned anything about this so now, let me know you, we can pass array as second argument array($this,'method').

**Description:**
when object creates of class then constructor automatically calls and your action performs.

**WHY IT REQUIRES**
in wordpress how to create or initialize the class in add_action method in short add_action referencing a class check below example

```
class Myclass{
 public function __construct() {


add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'load_plugin_textdomain' ) );

}
}
```

Referencing a class using add_action().